# How do we calculate the integral $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{\ln(x + 1)}{2x + 2}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification, logarithms

I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int_1^e \frac{\ln(x+1)}{2x+2} dx$$
so I make a substitution
$$ t \rightarrow x + 1$$ and so
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_2^{e+1} \frac{\ln(t)}{t} dt$$
and substitution again
$$ u \rightarrow \ln(t)$$

so therefore
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\ln(2)}^{\ln(e+1)} u du$$

and I believe that the final result should be
$$\frac{\ln(e+1)^2 - \ln(2)^2}{4}$$

but in the exam I have taken, the only solution was

$$\frac{\ln(2)^2}{4}$$
unfortunately, my professor is away and I cannot contact him so I am wondering, if the professor made a mistake with the solution.
Thanks

Comment: Your computations are correct.

Comment: [WolframAlpha also agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+ln%28x%2B1%29%2F%282x%2B2%29+dx+from+1+to+e) with you.

Comment: The exam result would come from limits $x=0,\,x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You are right indeed as you can check next:

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{e}\frac{\ln(x + 1)}{2x + 2}\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{e}\ln(x + 1)\mathrm{d}(\ln(x + 1))\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\ln(2)}^{\ln(e + 1)}u\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\left(\ln^{2}(e + 1) - \ln^{2}(2)\right)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!